# Join two subqueries and have a field: division of the results of two subqueries

Tags: mysql, postgresql, join, subquery

I have a table like this:

```
 userid | trackid | path
  123      70000     ad
  123      NULL     abc.com
  123      NULL     Apply
  345      70001    Apply
  345      70001    Apply
  345      NULL     Direct
  345      NULL     abc.com
  345      NULL     cdf.com
```

And I want a query like this. When path='abc.com', num_website +1; when path='Apply', num_apply +1

```
  userid | num_website | num_Apply | num_website/num_Apply
   123         1            1             1
   345         1            2            0.5
```

My syntax looks like this:

```
select * from 
(select userid,count(path) as is_CWS
from TABLE
where path='abc.com'
group by userid
having count(path)>1) a1
JOIN
(select userid,count(userid) as Apply_num from         
where trackid is not NULL
group by userid) a2 
on a1.userid=a2.userid
```

My question is 
1. how to have the field num_website/num_apply in term of my syntax above?
2. is there any other easier way to get the result I want?

Any spots shared will appreciate.

Comment: what is the column alias "is_CWS" ? or is it num_website ? And the where clause " track_id is not null" is applicable to the top part of your query (aliased as a1)  ? Take a look at my query which does it differently

Comment: You have no primary key. This is likely to prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to change the select line:

`SELECT a1.userid, a1.is_CWS, a2.Apply_num, a1.is_CWS/a2.Apply_num FROM
(select userid,count(path) as is_CWS
from TABLE
where path='abc.com'
group by userid
having count(path)>1) a1
JOIN
(select userid,count(userid) as Apply_num
from TABLE
where trackid is not NULL
group by userid) a2 
on a1.userid=a2.userid`

and then continue with the rest of your query as you have it.  The star means "select everything."  If you wanted to select only a few things, you would just list those things in place of the star, and if you wanted to select some other values based on those things, you would put those in the stars as well.  In this case `a1.is_CWS/a2.Apply_num` is an expression, and MySql knows how to evaluate it based on the values of a1.is_CWS and a2.Apply_num.

In the same vein, you can do a lot of what those subqueries are doing in a single expression instead of a subquery.  objectNotFound has the right idea.  Instead of doing a subquery to retrieve the number of rows with a certain attribute, you can select `SUM(path="abc.com") as Apply_num` and you don't have to join anymore.  Making that change gives us:

`SELECT a1.userid,
   SUM(path="abc.com") as is_CWS,
   a2.Apply_num,
   is_CWS/a2.Apply_num FROM
TABLE
JOIN
(select userid,count(userid) as Apply_num
FROM TABLE
where trackid is not NULL
group by userid) a2 
on a1.userid=a2.userid
GROUP BY userid`

Notice I moved the GROUP BY to the end of the query.  Also notice instead of referencing a1.is_CWS I now reference just is_CWS (it's no longer inside the a1 subtable so we can just reference it)

You can do the same thing to the other subquery then they can share the `GROUP BY` clause and you won't need the join anymore.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me and it works now. For the second way you mentioned, it is not working on my DB. There is duplicate issue. I guess probably I am using PostgreSql in redshift. Another question is if you are also familiar with Postgresql in redshift, do you know how to appear the division as decimal format?

Answer (score 0):

to get you started ... you can build on top of this :

```
select 
userid,
SUM(CASE WHEN path='abc.com'then 1 else 0 end ) as  num_website,
SUM(CASE WHEN path='Apply' and trackid is not NULL then 1 else 0 end ) as Apply_Num
from TABLE
WHERE path='abc.com' or path='Apply' -- may not need this ... play with it
group by userid
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for downvote so we can fix the problem ... (whoever did that) thx.